# TeleBot: "Infinity polling exception: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, bots, telegram, telebot

I am using Telebot (pyTelegramBotAPI) to run my telegram bot. I am running it on AWS within ECS in a Docker container.
Unfortunately, randomly it errors out: `TeleBot: "Infinity polling exception: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))`
It might happen once a day or 20 times a day with random occurence.

At first I just used `bot.polling()`, then, following some advices online, I switched to more sophisticated:

```
while True:
    try:
        bot.infinity_polling(timeout=60, long_polling_timeout=60, none_stop=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Exception is: {e}")
        sleep(5)
```

Unfortunately, nothing helps and I still get the same error.

I also don't understand how can infinity polling error happen if I added an exception handler to deal with it.
I would really appreciate your help, since I can find nothing online that helps to tackle the problem

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error but it looks the infinity_polling is continued nevertheless.

It looks like a caught internal exception in TeleBot implement.

Comment: My docker container stops when  this error appears